# Salesforce use Date/Time Field in Get Records with Flow

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-flow

I try archive the following: After 24 hours an EMail was sent I like to sent a follow up.

My problem is, I need to use a Date/Time field to identify the records, because MessageSent from EmailMessages is a Date/Time field.

Is there a way without creating a new field? Because alle the data is available, but needs to be transformes somehow.

Thanks!

Get the correct Record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this without creating a new field by using SOQL (Salesforce Object Query Language). You can use the `DATEDIFF` and `NOW` functions to filter out the records based on the difference in time between the current date and the `MessageSent` field.

Here's a sample query that retrieves EmailMessage records that were sent exactly 24 hours ago:

```sql
SELECT Id, Subject, MessageSent, ToAddress
FROM EmailMessage
WHERE DATEDIFF('hour', MessageSent, NOW()) = 24
```

This query will return the EmailMessage records where the difference between the `MessageSent` field and the current time is exactly 24 hours.

You can then use this information to send a follow-up email programmatically by iterating over the returned records and sending an email through Apex code or Process Builder.

Hope it helps

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).